# Adding Buttons To Google Sheets and Set value to Cells on clicking

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am new to Google Script.

I have a Google Sheet with 5 columns, on each column I need a button (with text `1,2,3,4,5`).

And on each button click I need to set text of button to corresponding cell and hide the clicked button.

Is it possible?

Comment: The buttons would be acessed by logged in Spreadsheet Editors or by Anonymous?

Comment: By logged in Spreadsheet ..

Comment: You can't make various buttons inside a cell, but you can make a dropdown selection with validation or a sideBar/dialog for the buttons (both theses methods require the user to be logged in). Button just hover the cells, I guess you could make many appear programatically, but I'm not sure how to.

Answer (score 16):

You can insert an image that looks like a button.  Then attach a script to the image.

- INSERT menu
- Image

[image: Insert Image]

You can insert any image.  The image can be edited in the spreadsheet

[image: Edit Image]

Image of a Button

[image: Image of Button]

Assign a function name to an image:

[image: Assign Function]

Comment: thanks for your answer..is it possible to add buttons with Google scripts

Comment: No.  There is no way to add a button to the spreadsheet with a script.  You can have a dialog box pop up, or put a sidebar on the side.  And the sidebar is HTML, so that can have a button.

Answer (score 6):

Consider [building an Add-on](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/quickstart/docs) that has an actual button and not using the outdated method of linking an image to a script function.

In the script editor, under the Help menu >> Welcome Screen >> link to Google Sheets Add-on - will give you sample code to use.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to insert an image in a Google Spreadsheet using Google Apps Script. However, the image should have been hosted publicly over internet. At present, it is not possible to insert private images from Google Drive.

You can use following code to insert an image through script.

```
  function insertImageOnSpreadsheet() {
  var SPREADSHEET_URL = 'INSERT_SPREADSHEET_URL_HERE';
  // Name of the specific sheet in the spreadsheet.
  var SHEET_NAME = 'INSERT_SHEET_NAME_HERE';

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(SPREADSHEET_URL);
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME);

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(
      'https://developers.google.com/adwords/scripts/images/reports.png');
  var binaryData = response.getContent();

  // Insert the image in cell A1.
  var blob = Utilities.newBlob(binaryData, 'image/png', 'MyImageName');
  sheet.insertImage(blob, 1, 1);
}
```

Above example has been copied from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41020598/insert-image-into-spresheet-cell-from-drive-using-google-apps-script) link. Check noogui's reply for details.

In case you need to insert image from Google Drive, please check [this](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36760259) link for current updates.

Comment: just realised the button is not clickable on mobile phone. it works in browse using a mouse