# C# - Google Sheets API, how to retrieve an image place in cell?

Tags: c#, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have a .net core 3.1 console app that I need to use to connect to my Google Sheet and export data to a PDF file.
I can retrieve all the textual data using `service.Spreadsheets.Values.Get(spreadsheetId, $"{spreadsheetName}!C2:C8");`

The issue I'm facing is that in cells B2:B8 (those are merged cells) I have an image which I've uploaded from my local folder (Image -> Insert -> Image in cell -> Upload) and I can't seem to retrieve that image.
When I call `service.Spreadsheets.Values.Get(spreadsheetId, $"{spreadsheetName}!B2:B8");` the `Values` property returns `null`

I've tried using `=image("IMAGE_URL")` in the cell instead of uploading the image but that didn't work as well.
Also, the preferred option would be to use the first approach of uploading the image into the cell so I won't have to find where to store my images.

Is this even possible to accomplish?

Answer (score 1):

### That's a very popular [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/129384672)

However, as of now it has not been implemented yet - given that images in cells are a rather new feature.

There are however some workarounds - either using Apps Script or a `vlookup` formula, have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56733340/how-to-access-new-in-cell-image-from-google-apps-script/56736463#56736463).