# Extract images from Google Sheet to Drive and reinsert as links in other or next cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Here A post I found I try it but its didn't work or maybe I did something wrong I asked them but they didn't reply and delete the my post
Can you please help on it

[Extract In-line images from Google Sheet and reinsert as links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65966182/extract-in-line-images-from-google-sheet-and-reinsert-as-links)

My Sample File

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OMvyuzT6gvSyJ84IN4jctOZkijuR4yNo8BjeMcbPhC8/edit#gid=0

CHART CELL Extract images and send them to in Google Drive folder and create all images and reinsert them as links in the C column (optional Trigger it once a day at 9.15 am and delete images at 3.30 pm) or monthly will do or we do manually

While Extract Images to drive the Image Pixel size can be changed as I need

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. I have 2 questions. 1. What does `create all images as share` mean? 2. What filenames do you want to give the created image files?

Comment: Hi, Even my English is not well image name can be anything but if possible then the image name is the same A column NSE:PIGL.jpg
and no need to share its auto-share

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I proposed an answer. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your question and that was not useful for your situation, I apologize.

Comment: Sir, I have 121 scripts in A Column and tried many times but this error camas Can you check one time                       4:06:15 PM Notice Execution started
4:12:16 PM Error 
Exceeded maximum execution time     https://drive.google.com/file/d/10EDycm6hc2RUz-PueiU-HxNk6dKaQe2H/view?usp=sharing

Comment: About your new issue of `Error Exceeded maximum execution time`, in this case, please run the script by separating the number of rows.

Comment: can you show me an example or change code for multiple rows or guide to change like this """const range = sheet.getRange("A2:B", "E2:G" + sheet.getLastRow());
  sheet.getRange("A2:A, "E2:E").copyTo(temp.getRange("A2","E2"));"""

Comment: About `can you show me an example or change code for multiple rows or guide to change like this`, I would like to support you. In this case, can you post it as a new question? Because my answer is for your provided Spreadsheet. If you can cooperate to resolve your new question, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?

Comment: Sure will do tomorrow please thanks

Comment: Thank you for your response. When I saw your new question, I would like to check it.

Comment: Kindly check if you can help me with it... Thanks    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77057442/getting-error-while-if-its-more-then-25-extract-images-from-google-sheet-to-driv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to retrieve the chart created by `SPARKLINE` function as an image and save it as an image file. And, put the file URL in column "C".

#### Issue and workaround:

Unfortunately, in the current stage, the chart created by `SPARKLINE` function cannot be retrieved as an image. So, in this answer, I would like to use a workaround. The flow of this workaround is as follows.

1. Retrieve formulas from column "B".
2. Create a chart using the formula with Google Apps Script.
3. Retrieve a blob from the chart.
4. Create the chart as an image file.
5. Put the file URL in column "C".

When this flow is reflected in a sample script, it becomes as follows.

#### Sample script:

Before you use this script, please set the folder ID of the folder you want to create the image file.

```js
function myFunction() {
  const folderId = "###";  // Please set your folder ID.

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName("DATA");
  const range = sheet.getRange("A2:B" + sheet.getLastRow());
  const values = range.getValues();
  const formulas = range.getFormulas();
  const temp = ss.insertSheet("tempSheet");
  sheet.getRange("A2:A").copyTo(temp.getRange("A2"));
  const folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
  const urls = values.map(([v], i) => {
    const formula = formulas[i][1];
    if (formula.toUpperCase().includes("SPARKLINE")) {
      const f = formula.match(/\(([\w\s\S]*)\)/);
      if (f) {
        temp.getRange("B1").setFormula(`=${f[1]}`);
        SpreadsheetApp.flush();
        const r = temp.getRange("C1:C" + temp.getLastRow());
        const [, ...vv] = r.getValues().map(([c]) => c);
        const max = Math.max(...vv);
        const min = Math.min(...vv);
        const chart = temp.newChart()
          .setChartType(Charts.ChartType.SPARKLINE)
          .addRange(r)
          .setOption("showAxisLines", false)
          .setOption("showValueLabels", false)
          .setOption("vAxis", { textPosition: 'none', viewWindow: { max, min } })
          .setOption("width", 200)
          .setOption("height", 100)
          .setPosition(1, 1, 0, 0)
          .build();
        temp.insertChart(chart);
        r.clear();
        const blob = chart.getBlob().setName(`${v}.png`);
        temp.removeChart(chart);
        const file = folder.createFile(blob);
        return [file.getUrl()];
      }
    }
    return [null];
  }, []);
  sheet.getRange(2, 3, urls.length).setValues(urls);
  ss.deleteSheet(temp);
}
```

#### Testing:

When this script is run, the image files are created from the formulas of column "B". And, the file URLs are put into column "C". The filename of image file is created using the values of column "A". And, you can see the sample images of the created image files in the following image.

[image]

#### Note:

- This sample script is for your provided Spreadsheet. When you change the Spreadsheet, this script might not be able to be used. Please be careful about this.
- About your new request of `While Extract Images to drive the Image Pixel size can be changed as I need`, in this case, please modify `.setOption("width", 200)` and `.setOption("height", 100)` for your situation.

#### References:

- [insertChart(chart)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#insertchartchart)
- [Class EmbeddedChart](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/embedded-chart)

Comment: Thank you so much, It's working very well and nicely,

Comment: HI, @tanaike I like to increase the thinness of chart lines using this formula  =SPARKLINE(GOOGLEFINANCE(A6,"Price",today()-365,today()),{"color","#00000";"linewidth",2}) is it possible Sir

Comment: @Sanjay Devani About your new question of `HI, @tanaike I like to increase the thinness of chart lines using this formula =SPARKLINE(GOOGLEFINANCE(A6,"Price",today()-365,today()),{"color","#00000";"linewidth",2}) is it possible Sir`, I would like to support you.

Comment: @Sanjay Devani But, the issue of your comment is new issue, and that is different from your question. So can you post it as new question by including the detail information? Because when your initial question is changed by comment, other users who see your question are confused. By posting it as new question, users including me can think of it. If you can cooperate to resolve your new issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to resolve your new question?