# Getting Error while if its more then 25 Extract images from Google Sheet to Drive and reinsert as links in other or next cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Fetting error if more then 25 Entry

```
Error Exceeded maximum execution time
```

Kindly Please Help me to sole it here is link for test file code also in that https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OMvyuzT6gvSyJ84IN4jctOZkijuR4yNo8BjeMcbPhC8/edit#gid=0

```
function myFunction() {
  const folderId = "1Tyy-ZjkNaMF6RPaYqgXwMsyeoRy0LkLl";  // Please set your folder ID.

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName("DATA");
  const range = sheet.getRange("A2:B" + sheet.getLastRow());
  const values = range.getValues();
  const formulas = range.getFormulas();
  const temp = ss.insertSheet("tempSheet");
  sheet.getRange("A2:A").copyTo(temp.getRange("A2"));
  const folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
  const urls = values.map(([v], i) => {
    const formula = formulas[i][1];
    if (formula.toUpperCase().includes("SPARKLINE")) {
      const f = formula.match(/\(([\w\s\S]*)\)/);
      if (f) {
        temp.getRange("B1").setFormula(`=${f[1]}`);
        SpreadsheetApp.flush();
        const r = temp.getRange("C1:C" + temp.getLastRow());
        const [, ...vv] = r.getValues().map(([c]) => c);
        const max = Math.max(...vv);
        const min = Math.min(...vv);
        const chart = temp.newChart()
          .setChartType(Charts.ChartType.SPARKLINE)
          .addRange(r)
          .setOption("showAxisLines", false)
          .setOption("showValueLabels", false)
          .setOption("vAxis", { textPosition: 'none', viewWindow: { max, min } })
          .setOption("width", 1000)
          .setOption("height", 250)
          .setPosition(1, 1, 0, 0)
          .build();
        temp.insertChart(chart);
        r.clear();
        const blob = chart.getBlob().setName(`${v}.png`);
        temp.removeChart(chart);
        const file = folder.createFile(blob);
        return [file.getUrl()];
      }
    }
    return [null];
  }, []);
  sheet.getRange(2, 3, urls.length).setValues(urls);
  ss.deleteSheet(temp);
}
```

I am looking for no error, its working fine time 25 entry if its more then that then its stop and get error  Error Exceeded maximum execution time

Comment: Dear Tanaike, I really appreciate your work I tried new scrips they work fine but sometimes it gets an error png like this https://drive.google.com/file/d/1j-IZlogfrq_wz_QetHo-La9kXshPIrAS/view?usp=sharing, but I am busy with something so not able to test so please bare with me will update you sooner

Answer (score 0):

I think that the reason for your current issue of `Error Exceeded maximum execution time` is due to that the number of rows for processing is large. In your provided Spreadsheet, 2096 formulas are required to be processed.

In your situation, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function myFunction() {
  const folderId = "1Tyy-ZjkNaMF6RPaYqgXwMsyeoRy0LkLl";  // Please set your folder ID.

  const start = new Date().getTime();
  const max = 300;
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName("DATA");
  const range = sheet.getRange("A2:C" + sheet.getLastRow());
  const values = range.getValues();
  const formulas = range.getFormulas();
  const temp = ss.insertSheet("tempSheet");
  sheet.getRange("A2:A").copyTo(temp.getRange("A2"));
  const folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
  const urls = [];
  let nextRun = false;
  for (let i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    console.log(`Current row number: ${i + 2}`);
    const v = values[i][0];
    const formula = formulas[i][1];
    if (!values[i][2] && formula.toUpperCase().includes("SPARKLINE")) {
      const f = formula.match(/\(([\w\s\S]*)\)/);
      if (f) {
        temp.getRange("B1").setFormula(`=${f[1]}`);
        SpreadsheetApp.flush();
        const r = temp.getRange("C1:C" + temp.getLastRow());
        const [, ...vv] = r.getValues().map(([c]) => c);
        const max = Math.max(...vv);
        const min = Math.min(...vv);
        const chart = temp.newChart()
          .setChartType(Charts.ChartType.SPARKLINE)
          .addRange(r)
          .setOption("showAxisLines", false)
          .setOption("showValueLabels", false)
          .setOption("vAxis", { textPosition: 'none', viewWindow: { max, min } })
          .setOption("width", 1000)
          .setOption("height", 250)
          .setPosition(1, 1, 0, 0)
          .build();
        temp.insertChart(chart);
        r.clear();
        const blob = chart.getBlob().setName(`${v}.png`);
        temp.removeChart(chart);
        const file = folder.createFile(blob);
        urls.push([file.getUrl()]);
      }
    } else {
      urls.push([values[i][2]]);
    }
    if ((new Date().getTime() - start) / 1000 > max) {
      nextRun = true;
      break;
    }
  }
  if (urls.length > 0) {
    sheet.getRange(2, 3, urls.length).setValues(urls);
  }
  ss.deleteSheet(temp);
  if (nextRun) {
    ScriptApp.newTrigger("myFunction").timeBased().after(3 * 60 * 1000).create();
    console.log("Trigger for executing script was installed.");
  } else {
    console.log("Done.");
  }
}
```

- When this script is run, the values are retrieved from cells "A2:C" of "DATA" sheet. And, the script for creating the image file is run by checking the values of columns "B" and "C". And, in this case, when the processing time is over 5 minutes, the script is finished, and the time-driven trigger is installed. By this, the script is automatically run after 3 minutes.
- In this modification, the script checks column "C". When all cells of column "C" are embedded, the trigger is not installed. This indicates that the process is finished.

#### Note:

- When I saw your provided Spreadsheet, 2096 rows are existing. I'm worried that in this case, the maximum execution time of the time-driven trigger of 90 minutes/day might be over. If it's so, please run the script tomorrow.
- If you want to run the script continuously with manual operation without using the trigger, please remove the script after the line of `if (nextRun) {`. By this, you can manually continuously run the script.
- By the way, in your Spreadsheet, `#N/A` as the response value from the formula is existing. In this case, even when the chart is created, the value is not included. Please be careful about this.

Comment: @Sanjay Devani Thank you for replying. I apologize for my late response. I noticed your reply just now. When you reply to me, please comment it to my answer. By this, I can notice it. By the way, about your reply, it is due to `#N/A` from your formula. I have already mentioned in my answer. I apologize for my poor English skill. If you want to avoid this, please resolve `#N/A` from your formula. I deeply apologize for my poor English skill again.