# Get URL of inserted cell image from google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a spreadsheet with 5000 images in one cell and I would like to get in another cell the image hyperlink. Like the following:

[image]

My struggle is I am unsure where the image is saved, cause I cannot extract a hyperlink from the image.

Find below my example:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gmPHXn8avgiOTN-GoASw7410FzBmXhpClDh6rjq9_Ds/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Hi. There is no shortage of references to this topic on StackOverflow and other web sites. Would you please summarise your research so that we do not reinvent the wheel or propose a answer that you have already discounted.

Comment: Leaving aside the number of images (@5,000), it's possible to right click on an image cell, select "Show edit history", click _"Image"_, and the image is opened in a new tab disclosing the url.

Comment: Related:  Google Issue Tracker: [The image put into a cell cannot be retrieved using Class CellImage ](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/215575446/resources).

Comment: @Tedinoz Thx for your reply. Tbh I am unsure how to access the image in the cell. I searched a lot about solving this problem, but the only solution that I found yet is to get the images by hand. Like copy each single image by using the snipping tool from windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm writing this answer as a community wiki, since the issue was resolved from the comments section, in order to provide a proper response to the question.

Based on the images in the sample sheet you shared and to answer your question **"My struggle is I am unsure where the image is saved"** it seems that images were manually added  `Insert` > `Image` > `Insert image in cell`. Unfortunately, currently there isn't a method to get the images inserted in a cell, if you use the method `spreadsheets.get` it doesn't return the data.

In addition to the Google Issue Tracker shared above, you can also check [this one](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/157888759).

If you are looking to download the images in the sheet, looking for alternatives I found this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64040243/17926478) and tested `Pattern 1` from that answer and it exports images to your Google Drive.

Answer (score 2):

The OP has 5,000 images so a manual process is not particularly helpful. But for anyone who wants to try the manual process...

- open the spreadsheet
- select a cell containing an image
- right click on the cell, a popup menu will appear
- select "Show edit history" (about half way down the menu)
- if the history is "Added 'image'", then you can access a copy of the image

  - right click the word 'Image'
  - select "Save link as" OR "Open Link in new tab"
  - save the image

---

**Show edit history**

[image: show edit history]

---

**Edit History**

[image: edit histiry]

Answer (score 0):

There is now a new possibility: the "link" to the picture is available from the right-click on the cell, in this menu sh "Show edit history" and finally, in the small popover you should see the word "image" which is the link to the real picture