# How to get text from an image placed in a cell using Google Apps Script

Tags: image, google-apps-script, google-sheets, ocr

I want to get text from an image placed in a cell using Google Apps Script.
What code do I write in Google Apps Script?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NOT2s.png)

Can the cell be saved as an image and the text read?

Comment: Here's a complete example: https://workspace.google.com/blog/developers-practitioners/getting-started-with-the-google-vision-api-from-gsuite

Comment: Thanks for the response. but the image does not have a URL. It is only placed in a cell.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand the situation of `an image placed in a cell`. In order to correctly understand your situation, can you provide a sample Spreadsheet including it?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1J5Dy1-ao61PUbywjTr8d1Z_uud2iJRihHgB-1p-ua9U/edit?usp=sharing
sample Spreadsheet

Comment: Thank you for replying and providing the sample Spreadsheet. From your sample Spreadsheet, I proposed an answer. Please confirm it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You have a Google Spreadsheet where the images are put into the cells. In this case, the images are directly put into the cells without URLs and the built-in function. The images show some texts.
- You want to retrieve the images and retrieve the texts from the images.

Unfortunately, in the current stage, there are no built-in methods for directly retrieving the images in the cells. So, in this case, I use [this workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64040243) for retrieving the images from the cells. And, in order to convert the texts from the image, Drive API is used.

When these are reflected in a sample script, it becomes as follows.

### Usage:

#### 1. Install a Google Apps Script library.

In this workaround, [DocsServiceApp (Author: me)](https://github.com/tanaikech/DocsServiceApp) of a Google Apps Script library is used. Please install this library. You can see how to install it at [here](https://github.com/tanaikech/DocsServiceApp#how-to-install).

#### 2. Sample script.

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Spreadsheet. And, please set your sheet name.

```js
function myFunction() {
  const sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set your sheet name.

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const spreadsheetId = ss.getId();
  const ar = DocsServiceApp.openBySpreadsheetId(spreadsheetId).getSheetByName(sheetName).getImages();
  const res = ar.map(({ range, image }) => {
    const tempId = Drive.Files.insert({ mimeType: MimeType.GOOGLE_DOCS, title: "temp" }, image.blob).id;
    const text = DocumentApp.openById(tempId).getBody().getText();
    Drive.Files.remove(tempId);
    return { cell: range.a1Notation, text: text.trim() };
  });
  console.log(res);
}
```

- In this script, the images in the cells are retrieved using a library, and the images are converted to Google Documents. And, the text is retrieved from Google Documents.

#### 3. Enable Drive API.

Please enable Drive API at Advanced Google services. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services)

#### 4. Testing.

When the above script is run for your provided Spreadsheet, the following result can be seen in the log.

```json
[
  {"cell":"A1","text":"098765431 ZYX"},
  {"cell":"A2","text":"1234567890 abcdef"},
  {"cell":"A3","text":"098765431 ZYX"},
  {"cell":"A4","text":"1234567890 abcdef"},
  {"cell":"A5","text":"1234567890 abcdef"},
  {"cell":"A6","text":"098765431 ZYX"},
  {"cell":"A7","text":"098765431 ZYX"}
]
```

### Note:

- In this answer, I propose a simple method. When your sample Spreadsheet is used, the processing time was about 30 seconds. If your actual Spreadsheet has a lot of images, it might be required to split the cells and use the script. Please be careful about this.

### References:

- [DocsServiceApp (Author: me)](https://github.com/tanaikech/DocsServiceApp)
- [Files: insert](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/insert)
- [Files: delete](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/delete)

Comment: Thanks to your help I was able to implement it.