# Can I use Apps Script to launch the "Insert Image in Cell" dialog box within Google Sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Is it possible to use Google Apps Script to insert an image into a Sheets cell by launching the `Insert > Insert Image > Insert image in cell` dialog box?

All of the documentation I've read about Class CellImage references using `.setSourceUrl()` to build the image based on a URL. Ultimately, I just want to automate the capturing a photo via the webcam, so the user can just click a button on the sheet, rather than navigate through drop-down menus.

Thanks!

Comment: It's definitely possible to launch a dialog and capture an image from a url and what you do with it is up to you.

Comment: In your situation, how does the user select the image file?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56733340/how-to-access-new-in-cell-image-from-google-apps-script/68150830

Comment: But I *don't* want to use a URL as the image source. I would like the image to come from the webcam, like you can do via the Insert > Insert Image dropdown menu.

Comment: @TheMaster, I didn't see anything in that link about inserting an image from a webcam source. Did I miss something? Looks like a lot of the discussion was around working with the image object via GAS once it's already been inserted. My challenge is figuring how to insert the image in the first place, via the webcam. Thanks.

Comment: You can upload images from ios mobiles and probably others as well.  the input of type file on an ios gives you a choice to chose Photo Libray, Take Photo or Video or Choose File.  On my laptop it just gives you access to file explorer.  I used to take images of many of my receipts.  Of course now you can just have them sent to you.

Comment: @KeithL That would be simple client side html/javascript `<input type="file" accept="image/jpeg, image/png" />`.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file You can include this client side html/js in a modal dialog