Google sheet copy image from INSIDE cell to OVER cell



Column A
Column B




Cell 1
Cell 2


Cell 3
Cell 4



I would like images from cell 2 or 4 over cell 3 (& not inside the cell) dependant on what is in Cell 1.

Image 'KF2.jpg' in Cell 2.
Image 'KF4.jpg' in Cell 4.

I would like;

'KF2.jpg' over cell 3 when Cell 1 changes to 200.
'KF2.jpg' over cell 3 to change to 'KF4.jpg' when Cell 1 changes to
600.

I have tried scripts from the excellent 'Tanaike' that grab images from the web or Google drive but I can't find a way of changing an over-cell image. I also hope by grabbing them from the same Google sheet would be more future proof and faster to load.

I have used this script from Tanaike but would like to adapt to use an image from same sheet that can be changed;
Updated Code ...
function onEdit(e) {

  var editedRange = e.range.getA1Notation().toString();
  console.log(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast(editedRange))
  if (editedRange == "A1") {
    replacetTheImage();
  }
}

function replacetTheImage() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange("A1");
  var valueoftheA1 = ss.getValue();
     if(valueoftheA1 > 399){
//  console.log(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast("I was here 1"))
    var images = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1").getImages();
    var blob = DriveApp.getFileByID("1ArSLT7rCypMWeTpTrddwyvxh3sMmwjSh").getBlob(); // was 1bIz3v9UDp-qq8qWfM-CK_OxWl9m7d7qY
    images[0].replace(blob);
    
  }
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();

}

When I run replacetTheImage() from the script Editor I get Error Message ...
1:35:09 PM  Error   
TypeError: DriveApp.getFileByID is not a function
replacetTheImage    @ Code.gs:31

If I type 100 or 400 into A1 cell I get a pop up message bottom right of sheet showing A1
The way I add the blob in the first place is ...
function TanikeGDimageOverCells() {
const imageFileId = "0BxWwc9tEdCGOTHEtc3hLYl9vNGc";
const blob = DriveApp.getFileById(imageFileId).getBlob();
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().insertImage(blob, 1, 10);
}


First, I deeply apologize that my script was not useful for your situation. About your question, I think that in this case, first, it is required to retrieve the image in the cell as a blob. After the image in the cell is retrieved as a blob, I think that your script can be used. In order to retrieve an image in a cell, I think that this script might be able to be used in this thread. https://stackoverflow.com/a/64040243

Though I understand your end goal. I do think that the work around defeats the purposes of why you are trying to pull the image from Spreadsheet. Have you had the chance to use the replace function on this link? https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/over-grid-image

Thank you Tanaike. That thread looks far to advanced from my limited knowledge. Thank you Babanana, are any of you great coders able to show me how to write a simple script using either the replace(Url) or replace(Blob) functions for an overgrid image?. If all fails I have seen a way to import blob as Url and also delete blob by Tanaike (again Thank you both).

Sure let me create an answer based on my comment to show you how replace works and how this align with your current requirements.

Using Replace for OverGridImage
As requested I created a Simple Sample Code to Execute the Replace function on OverGridImage Class. I also took the liberty of using OnEdit(e), to call the function which automates the detection of the value on "A1". Due to limited information about your real case I can only create generic approach on how to do this which you can use or implement on your own project.
Sample Code
function onEdit(e) {

  var editedRange = e.range.getA1Notation().toString();
  console.log(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast(editedRange))
  if (editedRange == "A1") {
    replacetTheImage();
  }
}


function replacetTheImage() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange("A1");
  var valueoftheA1 = ss.getValue();
     if(valueoftheA1 > 399){
    console.log(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast("I was here 1"))
    var images = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1").getImages();
    var blob = DriveApp.getFileById("1bIz3v9UDp-qq8qWfM-CK_OxWl9m7d7qY").getBlob();
    images[0].replace(blob);
    
  }
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();

}

Sample Output
Before:

After

References:
OnEdit - Triggers
Image.Replace(Blob)

Note: Please feel free to comment if you have more questions about this.


Thank you Babanana. This seems like what I am after. BUT when I add 100 to cell A1 I get a little comment box appear in the bottom right corner of the sheet with A1 inside. If I change A1 cell to 400 I get 'I was here 1'. I do not get the floating images like your example. Not sure what is wrong?

So "I was here 1" part was a result of a toast. Please remove this "console.log(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast("I was here 1"))". How did you try to run it may I ask? Do you encounter any errors on your end? Did you have a starter image to replace?

Can you add the whole code to your post including my answer it is just a little bit tricky to read in the comment section. Please copy the whole code involved in this so I can also see where it got the error.
