# Insert an image into a Google Spreadsheet that executes its own code when clicked by a user

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-apps

I'm creating a spreadsheet that lets a user select an item from a custom menu, then automatically populates the sheet with relevant data for the item they chose to add. Think of it like a configurator for a burger, where users can click "Add tomato" and the spreadsheet automatically creates a line item for tomato and adjusts the total cost of the burger at the bottom.

I also need a way to selectively delete items the user no longer wants.

I'm trying to insert an image next to each item that resembles an X symbol, and attach code to that image that will delete the corresponding item and all associated data.

The insertImage() function doesn't seem to allow this.  Any ideas?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1. You can manually create a button (an image with a script linked).  Click the arrow at the top right of an embedded image and select "Assign script..."

[image]

2. You can program your own add-on (or find an add-on that someone else created that does the exact thing you're looking for).  See https://developers.google.com/apps-script/quickstart/docs

At this time it is not possible to attach a script to an image that was added using Google Apps Script

Also addressed in [Adding Buttons To Google Sheets and Set value to Cells on clicking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28668766/adding-buttons-to-google-sheets-and-set-value-to-cells-on-clicking)