# Copy/Paste and merging data between two sheets with a button and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, automation, copy-paste

Currently I'm trying to setup a rental tracking spreadsheet in google sheets, for a DJ tech store.
I would need some help with scripting a code for the "Add" button (see pictures in the links).

[Sheet 1](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-HF8VUR-w2K4/WmeCe9gBRuI/AAAAAAAAAA4/qNf50dcg7dIWB2jM5cV0JDzZHznlITQ7wCLcBGAs/s1600/Screen%2BShot%2B2018-01-23%2Bat%2B20.31.11.png)
[Sheet 2](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-SNoC35in9Xk/WmeCiBg_3NI/AAAAAAAAAA8/15VocOZ1064QYracW_QN3F5HaX9KokE3ACLcBGAs/s1600/Screen-Shot-2018-01-23-at-20.30.45.png)

The functions might be quite simple to conceive, yet a bit tricky to code, therefore I'm here to ask for your help, ideas and suggestions.

What I would like to achieve is: By the click on the "Add" button on Sheet1, the data gets copy/pasted in the respective columns on the next empty row in the Sheet2.

Elaborating, I would need the code for a couple of strings like:

`//select next empty row in Sheet2
 //transfer and merge Sheet1 B5+B6 to Sheet2 column B (like Name space Surname)
 //transfer Sheet1 B8 to Sheet2 column C
 //transfer and merge Sheet1 D3:E12 to Sheet2 column D like "E3,'x ',D3,' + ',E4,'x ',D4,' + ',... and so on" 
 //transfer Sheet1 B10 to Sheet2 column E
 //transfer Sheet1 B12 to Sheet2 column F
 //transfer Sheet1 B18 to Sheet2 column G`

Any help or suggestion would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you for you time and effort.

Original post here: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/jXG-LV0dTSU;context-place=forum/docs

Comment: Please share a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: It looks you are asking others to write code for you. Do some research, write some code and post specific questions about the problem you have with the code.

Comment: Hey! Thank you guys for your attention! I probably forgot to mention that I’m totaly new to all excel/g.spreadsheets, javascript and g.app script. Currently, to create the mentioned functions I’m sincerly clueless even after doing reserch all over google, therefore I decided to finally post here and ask for help. Any link to related/helpfull topics would be much apreciated. Also the mentioned functions are just a part of the code that I want the button to execute, so far by reserching stuff up I’we been able to create the reset button, but fo the rest i’m clueless.

Comment: To help you start with, you can refer to this documentation about [Quickstart: Macros, Menus, and Custom Functions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/quickstart/macros). Also, if you need assistance on adding buttons, there is a discussion in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28668766/adding-buttons-to-google-sheets-and-set-value-to-cells-on-clicking). From the [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28677553/8342742), you will see illustrated step by step guide to create a button.