# Assign a script to a button in Google Docs

Tags: google-sheets, google-docs, google-docs-api

I want to assign a button to a script function. In Google Sheets, I would right-click, and select a script. I've tried to do the same thing in Google Docs but I don't see the option.Any ideas where is this option? Thank you. :)

Comment: it's currently not possible to do this in Google Docs

Comment: Here, follow the answer in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28677553/8342742). It is not possible to add a button in spreadsheet with a script, workaround is to have a dialog box pop up, or put a sidebar on the side. Additionally, there are numerous tutorials in YouTube just like [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sDMY9o23uBM).

Comment: Thanks ^^^I thought that team Google improved this fonction since Jul 3 '17