# Linking a hyperlink to a google form in a button

Tags: html

I would like to be able to access my google form by simply pressing a button.

I have drawn a button and the hyperlink I would like to link it to is - https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSdupUHV2uO6q69BHXvPzE1DgJu32HYQ31zPdyZ5uflmOftXRw/viewform","https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSdupUHV2uO6q69BHXvPzE1DgJu32HYQ31zPdyZ5uflmOftXRw/viewform

Any help writing this code would be brilliant

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create an HTML button that acts like a link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906582/how-to-create-an-html-button-that-acts-like-a-link)

Answer (score 1):

```
<form action="link-to-google-form" method="POST">
<input type="submit" value="Go" style="width:65%;height:40;" />
</form>
```

Change the width/height/other style options to your liking.

Comment: True, I suppose they're more looking for how to attach a hyperlink to a photo.

Comment: Thank you but how do I actually do this from start to finish in Google Sheets? (I am a novice).

When I try to assign script I get an error stating the script function could not be found

Comment: I'm confused about what you're asking. Are you trying to put the button on your website?

Comment: I have a Google Sheet which has a Google Form built in to it. I would like to create a button on the spreadsheet which directs me straight to the Google Form when I click it. The hyperlink for my Google Form is in the original question.

Thank you

Comment: You're asking about google script not html. Maybe this can help point you in the right direction: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28668766/adding-buttons-to-google-sheets-and-set-value-to-cells-on-clicking

Answer (score 0):

`<a href='URL GOES HERE'><img src="link-to-photo"></a>`

Answer (score 0):

easily you can use (a) tag in css :

```
<a href="https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSdupUHV2uO6q69BHXvPzE1DgJu32HYQ31zPdyZ5uflmOftXRw/viewform" >
    Text to show in your link 
</a>
```

and if you want your link seems like buttons you can use this code with styles:

```
<a style="display: inline-block; padding: 6px 12px; margin-bottom: 0; font-size: 14px; font-weight: 400; line-height: 1.42857143; text-align: center; white-space: nowrap; vertical-align: middle; -ms-touch-action: manipulation; touch-action: manipulation; cursor: pointer; -webkit-user-select: none; -moz-user-select: none; -ms-user-select: none; user-select: none; background-image: none; border: 1px solid transparent; border-radius: 4px;color: #333;background-color: #fff;border-color: #ccc;" href="https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSdupUHV2uO6q69BHXvPzE1DgJu32HYQ31zPdyZ5uflmOftXRw/viewform" >
        Text to show in your link 
    </a>
```

Its better to copy `<a>` style content in to your css file.
If you want change color of button just change background-color and color in `<a>` style.