# On Google Sheets, I would like to create a button that acts as a link when clicked on

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

The link within the button is a link to a linked Google Form.
I know how to draw a button, but do not know how to write and assign the script to the button / image.

The link I need the button to execute is:
https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSdupUHV2uO6q69BHXvPzE1DgJu32HYQ31zPdyZ5uflmOftXRw/viewform

All help would be much appreciated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding Buttons To Google Sheets and Set value to Cells on clicking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28668766/adding-buttons-to-google-sheets-and-set-value-to-cells-on-clicking)

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

1) On the Script Editor (Tools > Script Editor) add this function (I already added your form URL):

```
function openForm(){

  var html = "<script> window.open('https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSdupUHV2uO6q69BHXvPzE1DgJu32HYQ31zPdyZ5uflmOftXRw/viewform');</script>";
  var ui = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html)
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(ui,"demo");

}
```

2. Save your script (Ctrl + S).
3. Back to your Sheet, click on your button > click on the three dots > **Assign cript...** > Enter **openForm**

Voilà! When you click on the button the Form will be opened in a new tab. Just note you might need to allow pop-ups.